# Coercion in MAGMA

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

In MAGMA, if you are dealing with an element $x\in H$ for some group $H$, and you know that $H<G$ for some group $G$, is there an easy way to coerce $x$ into $G$ (e.g. if $H=\text{Alt}(n)$ and $G=\text{Alt}(n+k)$ for some $k\geq 1$)? The natural coercion method $G!x$ does not seem to work.

Comment: I think holding someone over magma is probably a good method of coercion. (Apologies for the nonconstructive comment, but I couldn't resist.)

Comment: Why didn't I think of that!

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake for using the worng MAGMA tag! Many apologese.

Comment: No need to apologize; after all, the correct tag didn't even exist when you asked this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

G!CycleDecomposition(g);

will work

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful responses.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to define the inclusion homomorphism $H \hookrightarrow G$ and apply it to your element $x$.  See http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/547#5783 for how to define homomorphisms.